# php how to insert query result from server 1 to server 2 table in mySQL php

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

I'm new to PHP first of all ..

My question is once I got the $result from Server1 using mysql_query , how can I create Table2 that would stored in host2

```
<?php

$connect1 = mysql_connect(host1,user,pass);
$selected = mysql_select_db(database1,$connect1);

$result = mysql_query("select a,b,c from table1");

$connect2 = mysql_connect(host2,user,pass);
$selected = mysql_select_db(database2,$connect2);

mysql_query("create table table2 as select $result from table2"); 

?>
```

They are two different servers (both in MySQL) .. answer in details would appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Let me caution you to use either the [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) extension or [`PDO`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for database operations. `mysql` is a dinosaur that's [on the way out](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). You'll be much better served using one of the other methods I've mentioned.

Comment: I agree with @rdlowrey. My answer below works just the same with mysqli and it is even simpler with PDO. PDO is usually my connection of choice.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, Can you show me how to do PDO on this similar purpose ? I would really appreciated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_query` accepts two parameters. The second is the connection, have you tried this?

```
mysql_query("create table table2 as select $result from table2", $connect2);
```

PHP Documentation on `mysql_query`:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php